# password recovery for SyBase file

Tags: credentials, sqlanywhere, password-recovery, sybase-asa

I have a `.db` file that I think is a Sybase database file that I have been tasked with extracting data from. Looking at the file in notepad shows that the data in not encrypted (I can read text strings from it) but I don't have the username/password to convince the Sybase tools to read it.

Are there any tools/procedure that just skip the credentials check?

(BTW the client owns the data so it's all legit)

Answer (score 2):

I'd be surprised if it were that easy to get around Sybase security ... but one never knows. Have you tried the default username (dba) and password (sql)? You'd be surprised how many people are too lethargic to change it!

Comment: I'd be just a bit surprised if the SyBase tools gave a work around but not a bit surprised if some 3rd party has written a tool that loads the file without bothering about the authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a Sybase SQL Anywhere or Sybase IQ database, there are no tools that Sybase supplies that can access the data without supplying a valid user name / password. If there are any third party tools that can do this (I don't know of any), we certainly don't sanction them.

*Full disclosure*: I work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering.

Comment: I would be disaponted if you did sanction such a tool. As it happens, I managed to get a new copy of the DB from the original owner that has a know password (some default IIRC) so this became moot.

Answer (score -2):

under ASE (Adaptive Server Entreprise), default userID: "sa", pass:""